# docker USER not getting executed first, why?

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux

```
FROM alpine:3.10

RUN apk add --update

USER node

RUN mkdir /home/node/code

WORKDIR /home/node/code

COPY --chown=node:node package-lock.json package.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

This is my Dockerfile. When I execute this command `docker run --init --rm -P --name node-app node-app-apline`. I get this error:

```
 => ERROR [3/7] RUN mkdir /home/node/code                                                                                                                                                          
  1.3s
 ------
 [3/7] RUN mkdir /home/node/code:
 ------
 executor failed running [/bin/sh -c mkdir /home/node/code]: unable to find user node: 
 no matching entries in passwd file
```

The thing is.. somehow or the other the `RUN mkdir /home/node/code` gets executed. Why?
Is this something to do with cache? I don't know.

PS: I'm new to asking questions, please help me if there is something wrong with my question. Also, I'm new to docker too.

Comment: The `USER` instruction only sets the active user. It does not create an entry in `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow`.

Comment: Can you post the answer, please? I didn't get it.

Comment: The answer is: the `USER` instruction gets executed as 2nd step. The order is not the problem. The problem is that there is no entry for user `node` in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: So, I need to basically make an entry for node. How is that to be done?

Comment: I'm new to docker as I mentioned. it's a bit confusing to me.

Comment: See the [`useradd` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd).

Comment: The `node:alpine` image already has a node user defined, so unless you want to create the image yourself, you could use that as your base image. If you want to see the Dockerfile for that image, it's here: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/ef329f2c98916eca9a913774788b576573bd8aff/17/alpine3.14/Dockerfile